# Invalid free() after closedir()

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, memory-leaks

I implemented a simple version of ls called myls, and when I try to free the linked list created in the program, I get invalid free() notice, I think it has something to do with closedir() but I don't know exactly why, **here is the memory leak check**:(*** indicates personal information)

```
******:~/***/***/myls$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes myls
==742== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==742== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==742== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==742== Command: myls
==742== 
.
..
Makefile
myls
myls.c
tests
==742== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==742==    at 0x4C2A82E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==742==    by 0x4009D2: freeList (in /p2/hh/***/***/***/myls/myls)
==742==    by 0x400AE2: main (in /p2/hh/***/***/***/myls/myls)
==742==  Address 0x51f0083 is 67 bytes inside a block of size 32,816 alloc'd
==742==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==742==    by 0x4EECD5A: __alloc_dir (opendir.c:202)
==742==    by 0x400A0B: main (in /p2/hh/***/***/***/myls/myls)
==742== 
==742== 
==742== HEAP SUMMARY:
==742==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==742==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 13 frees, 32,912 bytes allocated
==742== 
==742== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==742== 
==742== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==742== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

**and here is my code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct n{
    char *key;
    struct n *next;
} node;
node *list = NULL;

// errorCheck(*myDir) -- check if the target directory is opened
// correctly or print out an error message if not and exit.
void errorCheck(DIR *myDir){
    if (myDir == NULL){
        perror("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
}

// buildList(*myDir) -- create a list containing
// all directories' name.
node *buildList(DIR *myDir){
    struct dirent *dirPtr;
    node *temp = NULL;

    // put into list
    while ((dirPtr = readdir(myDir)) != NULL){
        temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (temp == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: out of memory!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        temp -> key = dirPtr -> d_name;
        temp -> next = list;
        list = temp;
    }

    return temp;
}

// printList(*list) -- print out the linked list.
void printList(node *list){
    node *temp = NULL;

    temp = list;
    while (temp != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", temp -> key);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
}

// swap(*n1, *n2) -- swap keys of these two nodes.
void swap(node *n1, node *n2){
    char *temp;
    temp = n1 -> key;
    n1 -> key = n2 -> key;
    n2 -> key = temp;
}

// sortList(*list) -- use bubble sort to sort the
// linked list in alphabetic order.
void sortList(node *list){
    node *curr, *last = NULL;
    int changed;

    do{
        changed = 0;
        curr = list;

        while (curr -> next != last){
            if (strcmp(curr -> key, curr -> next -> key) > 0){
                swap(curr, curr -> next);
                changed = 1;
            }
            curr = curr -> next;
        }
        last = curr;
    } while (changed == 1);
}

// freeList() -- free up the linked list.
void freeList(){
    node *temp = list;

    while (list != NULL){
        temp = list;
        list = list -> next;
        free(temp -> key);
        free(temp);
    }
}

// main() -- main structure of the program
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    DIR *myDir;

    if (argc == 1){
        myDir = opendir(".");
        errorCheck(myDir);
        list = buildList(myDir);
        sortList(list);
        printList(list);
        closedir(myDir);
    }
    else if(argc == 2){
        myDir = opendir(argv[1]);
        errorCheck(myDir);
        list = buildList(myDir);
        sortList(list);
        printList(list);
        closedir(myDir);
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: too many arguments!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    freeList();
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: This `temp -> key = dirPtr -> d_name;` should be making a copy `strdup` or the `malloc` route. Even use `MAX_PATH_LEN` in your structure and do `strcpy`

Comment: Oh my god, that's the solution and I missed it, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem - I just look like a God :-)

Comment: You might as well delete the question if the comment solved the problem

Comment: You'd probably find that if you printed the list (before you freed anything), all the names were the same because there's a decent chance that `readdir()` reuses the same space each time it returns a file name.  Just another reason to use `strdup()` or a relative.  It's also why you got 6 copies of the error; you had 6 entries in the directory, so you freed the same space 6 times, but `closedir()` also freed it first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the memory allocation for temp->key explicitly, so my guess is that you shouldn't be calling free() on it.

```
// freeList() -- free up the linked list.
void freeList(){
    node *temp = list;

    while (list != NULL){
        temp = list;
        list = list -> next;
        **free(temp -> key);**
        free(temp);
    }
```

Info from: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html

```
   On success, readdir() returns a pointer to a dirent structure.  (This
   structure may be statically allocated; do not attempt to free(3) it.)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should read the comment that I made 12 minutes ago and propose a solution using that information

Comment: @ed-heal, I was looking into the problem to see where the issue is, which is what the problem statement is (and not the solution itself). It could be that your comments might have crossed paths with mine, before I looked further.  Yes, the solution then is to see what is missing from the code to make it work - standup(), strip(), malloc() + strlcpy()/strcpy() etc.  So, don't try to be sarcastic in your comments or responses.

Comment: @ed-heal, perhaps you could write, "I just posted comments on what I think the issue is, you may want to refer to it".  How does that sound for a change?

Comment: The poster has agree that was the problem

Comment: Good, now let @crysishy, decide on what he wanted to do next.  Then he could comment accordingly.

Comment: My great appreciation to EdHeal and Ravi, you guys both offered some solid information on solving this problem, and I learned from it. Thank you ;)